# Yii2:how to get return value in view from model?

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions

I have a table name "staff".Staff table has one to many relation with attendance table.

In model `Staff.php`

```
public function getAttendances()
    { 
        if(isset($_GET['startdat']))
        $start_date=$_GET['startdat'];
        if(isset($_GET['enddate']))
        $end_date=$_GET['enddate'];
        if(isset($_GET['startdat'])){
        return $this->hasMany(Attendance::className(), ['staff_id' => 'id'])
                ->where('daytime >= "'.$start_date.'" and daytime<="'.$end_date.'"');
        }
        else{
        return $this->hasMany(Attendance::className(), ['staff_id' => 'id'])
                ->andOnCondition(['daytime' => 'Absent'])
                ->orOnCondition(['status' => 'Present'])
                ->orOnCondition(['status' => 'leave']);
        }


    }
public function getPresent(){
        $present=0;
              foreach($this->attendances as $attendance){ 
                  if($attendance->status=='Present')
                    $present++; 
                  } 
              return $present;
    }


    public function getAbsent(){
        $Absent=0;
              foreach($this->attendances as $attendance){ 
                  if($attendance->status=='Absent')
                  $Absent++; 
              } 
              return $Absent;
    }
    public function getLeave(){
        $Leave=0;
              foreach($this->attendances as $attendance){ 
                  if($attendance->status=='Leave')
                  $Leave++; 
              } 
              return $Leave;
    }
```

in views **report.php**

```
<?=

    GoogleChart::widget(['visualization' => 'PieChart',
                'data' => [
                    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                    ['Present', 5],
                    ['Absent', 2],
                    ['leave', 4],
                ],]);
?>
```

i want to get the  returned  value of `$present ,$Absent and $leave.` to make GoogleChart dynamic. How to echo the function returned value from model in view in yii2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for getting value from model's functions.

```
use path\to\model\Staff;
<?=
   GoogleChart::widget(['visualization' => 'PieChart',
                'data' => [
                    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                    ['Present', Staff::getPresent()],
                    ['Absent', Staff::getAbsent()],
                    ['leave', Staff::getLeave()],
                ],]);
?>
```

Comment: it give error "Undefined class constant 'getattendances' " .i used static function as ` public static function getPresent(){ $present=0; foreach(self::getattendances as $attendance){ if($attendance->status=='Present') $present++; } return $present; } `

Comment: you can try add static keyword in `getAttendances()` as `public static function getAttendances()`

Comment: You use "$this->getAttendances()" instead of "$this->attendances()“

Comment: still same error.... Actually i making mistake in foreach loop .this is foreach loop `foreach(self::attendances as $attendance) ` i d'nt know what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use static function

```
 public static function getAttendances()
 { 
  .......




 public static function getPresent(){
    $present=0;
          foreach(self::attendances() as $attendance){ 
              if($attendance->status=='Present')
                $present++; 
              } 
          return $present;
}


public static  function getAbsent(){
    $Absent=0;
          foreach(self::attendances() as $attendance){ 
              if($attendance->status=='Absent')
              $Absent++; 
          } 
          return $Absent;
}
public static function getLeave(){
    $Leave=0;
          foreach(self::attendances() as $attendance){ 
              if($attendance->status=='Leave')
              $Leave++; 
          } 
          return $Leave;
}
```

and the use in your widget

```
use path\to\model\Staff;
<?php echo GoogleChart::widget(['visualization' => 'PieChart',
            'data' => [
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Present', Staff::getPresent()],
                ['Absent', Staff::getAbsent()],
                ['leave', Staff::getLeave()],
            ],]);
?>
```

Comment: it give error "Undefined class constant 'getattendances' " .i used static function as ` public static  function getPresent(){
        $present=0;
              foreach(self::getattendances as $attendance){ 
                  if($attendance->status=='Present')
                    $present++; 
                  } 
              return $present;
    }`

Comment: still same error .My issue is here i think                                               `public static function getPresent(){
        $present=0;
              foreach(static::attendances as $attendance){ 
                  if($attendance->status=='Present')
                    $present++; 
                  } 
              return $present;
    }`

Comment: I have update the answer try with self::attendances() whit static for getAttendaces ()

Comment: still giving this error                                                                            `Call to undefined method app\models\Staff::Attendances() `

Comment: Try calling self::getAttendances()

Comment: I have already tried by calling `self::getAttendances()` then it give error `Using $this when not in object context` .Afterthat i change                                                                                              `public static  function getAttendances()
    {    if(isset($_GET['startdat'])){
         return self::hasMany(Attendance::className(), ['staff_id' => 'id'])
                ->where('daytime >= "'.$start_date.'" and daytime<="'.$end_date.'"');
        }  `                                       this lead to error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: i am getting value as                                                                        `[
   'attribute' => 'add',
   'value'=>'Present',
 ],`   it show total number of presents but  how to put it in googlecharts

Comment: explain better please i don't understand

Comment: in views i have report.php  where i used this code                  `[ 'attribute' => 'add', 'value'=>'Present', ] `   to get the return value of model method.but i have to used  this value within googlechart wiget .how to use googlecharts in gridview with these return values.......